# Multiple features of X in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

My question is this: How can I change my code if I want to use multiple input data (multiple features of X) like this (example):

```
trainX = np.array([[1,2], [2,2] ,[3,3.23] ,[4.11,4] ,  [5,5.11] , [6,6] ,[7,7], [8,8.1], [9,9],[10,10]])
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

# Teach "Table 3" to the network 
trainX = np.array([1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,  5 , 6 ,7, 8, 9,10])
trainY = np.array([3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30])

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, nb_epoch=1200, batch_size=2, verbose=2)


# Predict  3x20, answer = 60
dataPrediction = model.predict(np.array([4]))
print (int(dataPrediction[0][0]), '<--- Predicted number')
print ('12 <-- Correct answer \n')
```

**Output:**

```
12 <--- Predicted number
12 <-- Correct answer
```

Comment: Just change your `input_dim` to 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read documentation before asking question here: https://keras.io

Answer to your question:

In line **model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))** the input dimension parameter is to specify the input shape. When you are using feature vector of two dimension input_dim would be 2.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

# Teach "Table 3" to the network 
trainX = np.array([[1,2], [2,2] ,[3,3.23] ,[4.11,4] ,  [5,5.11] , [6,6] ,[7,7], [8,8.1], [9,9],[10,10]])

trainY = np.array([3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30])

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, nb_epoch=1200, batch_size=2, verbose=2)


# Predict  3x20, answer = 60
dataPrediction = model.predict(np.array([[4.11,4]]))
print (dataPrediction, '<--- Predicted number')
print ('12 <-- Correct answer \n')
```